# Hard-wrap multiple lines without selecting them?

Tags: wrapping

1. To hard-wrap a single line, we can use `gqq`,
2. and to hard-wrap multiple lines, we can select them in visual mode and then use the same `gqq` command.

However, I suppose that there is probably a smarter way to accompany the second task. Does it really exist?

So the following code

```
// a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
// b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b
```

should be hard-wrapped to

```
// a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
// a a a a a a a a a a a a a a b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b
// b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `gq` is an operator, it accepts motions and text-objects. My go-to is `gqip` in cases like this. With plugins you can often make things like `gqgc` (format a comment) or `gqii` (format this indented block) work, since the text-objects orthogonally extend all operators.